# jQuery Mobile Back button in Header for Div Tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, back-button

I have a div Tag with a ul tag. The ul tag becomes dynamically list elements li.
So what i want is to use the back button on the header to switch between the list elements.

Example for my list:

Mainmenu-->Submenu 1--> Submenu 2-->Data.

So if i'm in Submenu 2 and click the back button. I want to get in the Submenu 1.

```
<div data-role="header">
    <h1> Items </h1>
    <a id="backbtn" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="back" data-add-back-btn="true">Back</a>
</div>
```

Everytime if i click a listitem in the list. I clear the list and fill it with the new items. What is the easiest way for me to handle with my problem?

Comment: removeclass on click of back button..tried it??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aUPV2/

Comment: Is this ul tag also a jQUery Mobile listview or are you talking about classic ul element?

Comment: is jQuery mobile listview.